# Extracting polygon in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, digitizing

I need to define the boundary of a number of towns. I have found maps of some of the towns in google maps but have no idea how I can digitize or export them for use in ArcMap. So far i have not seen any tools in Google Maps that could be used.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Matt's answer, which is relatively easier, you can use [Google's My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/). Assuming you have a Google account, creating a map is explained [here](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024454?hl=en) and by using **draw a line** tool, you can create polygons. Even though it says line, the sub menu says **Add line or shape** and closing your line will create a polygon.

Once you finish your map, in the map options, you will find **Export to KML**. Then you can convert KML to ArcGIS vector formats by using [KML to Layer tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-to-layer.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Try Google Earth instead. Essentially the same as Maps, but you can draw shapes and export them as .kml files.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Apparently those maps where not proper boundary maps becuase a close examination showed they run through peoples property.  so i have had to rely on a source to provide the boundary maps. i need a boundary map for each of the communities i am working in and those can not be found in google maps or any other source.

Comment: Where abouts are you? You may be able to find the data you are looking for from local government, or similar.